# Javascript closure and events

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, eventemitter

I am facing following issue:

I am calling in foreach cycle following `browse` function. When the `rb.wsc.browse(symbol)` is called the program do some WebSocket request and when the message is returned the event is emmited. The problem is that I always get the same `browseData` even when I know that the event is emited with different one. I think that this is closure issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
function browse(rb, symbol, callback) {
    var result = function(wsc, browseData) {
        wsc.off('browse', result);
        wsc.off('failed', result);

        var err = null;
        if (wsc.errno < 0) {
            err = new Error("Browsing symbol " + symbol + " failed!");
            err.status = wsc.errno;
        } else {                
            saveBrowseData(rb, browseData);
        }
        callback(err, symbol);
    };
    // Register temporary listeners
    rb.wsc.on('browse', result);
    rb.wsc.on('failed', result);

    // Browse symbol
    rb.wsc.browse(symbol);
} 

RexBrowser.prototype.refresh = function() {
    var that = this;
    var browseRequestNumber = 1;

    var browseResult = function(err, symbol) {
        browseRequestNumber--;
        var item = that.getSymbol(symbol);

        _.each(item.children, function(child) {
            if (child.browse) {
                browseRequestNumber++;
                debug("Browsing: " + child.cstring);
                browse(that,child.cstring, browseResult);
            }
        });

        if (browseRequestNumber === 0) {
            that.emit('refresh', that);
        }
    };

    // Start recursive browsing
    browse(this,'$', browseResult);
};-
```

Comment: Well, you are using the same handler for all your events (`result`) and from this point on your handler uses the same callback for all events. So this is what you programmed as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeh, I can see it now also. I thought that when I call `var result` it will create new function every time I call `browse` function. So I will have several different handler. I found out that first emit of the event will deregister all listeners using `wsc.off` function. S I will have to introduce some tags for each call to recognize from which response are `browseData` comming from.

Comment: How does it matter that you create a new function if it does the same thing?

Comment: It should store the link to the `callback` function. When I browse some 'symbol' I want to be able to call callback function which belongs to the currently browsed 'symbol'. Basically whole code is part of the asynchronous recursive tree traversal.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
} else {
    function(rbInner, browseDataInner){
        saveBrowseData(rbInner, browseDataInner);
    }(rb, browseData);
}
```

This makes sure the variables used by / in `saveBrowseData` have the values they have when the function is called.

Comment: It is not helping. When I debug it it alwas calls the result function with the same `browseData` :(

Comment: At least +1 for the quick response, even the probem is on my side. Thank you